# The keyboard sometimes doesn't work

Tags: unity, 11.10, keyboard, gnome, gnome2

I just installed Oneiric. The problem that I have with the unity desktop is that it's slow, and sometimes the keyboard just stops working while the mouse moves and I can click. At the same time I can press ctrl-alt-f1 to go to login mode and kill Xorg to come back. The thing that bugs me is that this is hapenning a lot of times and I'm thinking about installing gnome 2. I tried installing gnome-session-fallback but this doesn't seem to be a good gnome2 shell.

Does anyone know how to solve the keyboard issue? Or anyone knows how to install a decent gnome shell on Oneiric?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself. Sometimes the focus goes to the left sidebar when the Windows button is pressed. Pressing ESC a few times makes it go away :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing to say about your keyboard problems, but installing Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 11.10 is quite easy: typing "sudo apt-get install gnome-shell" in a terminal and choosing Gnome-Shell from LightDM.  And yes, it's a "decent gnome shell", it's just the last version of it. ;)

It's simple.  It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try Alt-Tab (and a second time to get back to your app) instead of killing X.org.  I'm having similar keyboard problems after upgrading to 11.10 (Lenovo T420).